# SilverStripe - Create pagination based on dropdown selection

Tags: php, jquery, pagination, silverstripe

I am working on building out some pagination for a page on a SilverStripe site that is meant to show all articles at first by default, but the user can select which articles to view by selecting a year from a dropdown control.

Here is the template for the articles. Right now I have code in place that adds pagination when the page first loads or is reloaded and all articles are grabbed from the server:

```
<select id="SelectNewsYear">
    <option value="">Select a year</option>
    <% loop $GroupedNewsByDate.GroupedBy(PublishYear) %>
        <option value="$PublishYear">$PublishYear</option>
    <% end_loop %>
    <option value="all">Show all</option>
</select>
<br /><br />

<div class="RecentNews">
    <% loop $PaginatedReleases %>
       $ArticleDate.format("F j, Y"), <a href="$URLSegment">$H1</a><br />
    <% end_loop %>

    <% if $PaginatedReleases.MoreThanOnePage %>
        <% if $PaginatedReleases.NotFirstPage %>
            <a class="prev" href="$PaginatedReleases.PrevLink">Prev</a>
        <% end_if %>
        <% loop $PaginatedReleases.Pages %>
            <% if $CurrentBool %>
                $PageNum
            <% else %>
                <% if $Link %>
                    <a href="$Link">$PageNum</a>
                <% else %>
                    ...
                <% end_if %>
            <% end_if %>
        <% end_loop %>
        <% if $PaginatedReleases.NotLastPage %>
            <a class="next" href="$PaginatedReleases.NextLink">Next</a>
        <% end_if %>
    <% end_if %>
</div>
```

The PaginatedReleases function in Page.php:

```
//Returns a paginted list of news releases
public function PaginatedReleases(){
    $newslist = NewsReleaseArticlePage::get()->sort('ArticleDate', "DESC");
    return new PaginatedList($newslist, $this->getRequest());
}
```

The problem now is figuring out how to maintain the pagination feature whenever a year is selected from the dropdown. Initially, I did not concern myself with pagination as I was more concerned with the functionality of the dropdown list. This is the jQuery and AJAX code I have set up currently that grabs the year value from the dropdown list and passes it to the server to the appropriate function:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var SelectNewsYear = $('#SelectNewsYear');

        var month = new Array();
        month[0] = "January";
        month[1] = "February";
        month[2] = "March";
        month[3] = "April";
        month[4] = "May";
        month[5] = "June";
        month[6] = "July";
        month[7] = "August";
        month[8] = "September";
        month[9] = "October";
        month[10] = "November";
        month[11] = "December";


        SelectNewsYear.change(function() {

            if (SelectNewsYear.val() != "" && SelectNewsYear.val() != null &&  SelectNewsYear.find('option:selected').attr('value') !="all") {
                sendYear();
            }
            else{
                showAll();
            }
        });

        //get all articles by the year selected
        function sendYear(){
            var year = SelectNewsYear.find('option:selected').attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/home/getNewsByYear/"+year,
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function (response) {
                var list = '';
                var newsSection = $('.RecentNewsByYear');

                for (var i=0;i<response.length;i++){
                    var newsDate = new Date(response[i].date);
                    var monthFullName = month[newsDate.getUTCMonth()];

                    list += monthFullName + " " + newsDate.getUTCDate() +", " +newsDate.getFullYear()  + ', ' + '<a href="' + response[i].article + '"target="_blank">' + response[i].title +"</a> <br />";
                }
                newsSection.empty();
                newsSection.append(list);
            });
        }

    });
}(jQuery));

$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

And the getNewsByYear function from Page.php:

```
//Get all recent news by year based on selected year from dropdown
    public function getNewsByYear(){
        //Get the year selected by the dropdown
        $newsReleaseYear = $this->getRequest()->param('ID');

        //Group together all news that are associated with that selected year
        $newsReleases = NewsReleaseArticlePage::get();

        $return = array();

        //put the news releases into the array that match the selected year
        foreach($newsReleases as $newsRelease){
            $newsDate = date("Y", strtotime($newsRelease->ArticleDate));

            if($newsDate == $newsReleaseYear){
                $return[] = array(
                    'title' => $newsRelease->H1,
                    'date' => $newsRelease->ArticleDate,
                    'article' => $newsRelease->URLSegment
                );
            }
        }

        return json_encode($return);
    }
```

The getNewsByYear function works fine as is, but I am not sure how to incorporate the SilverStripe PaginationList feature here. I am wondering if there is a way to return the selected articles without relying on json encoded data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's definitely room for improvement when you return JSON to build HTML markup from JSON…

I also think it's good practice to write your application logic in a way that works without JS, then add the JS to progressively enhance your application. That way you don't lock out every non-JS device/reader/user.

So here's what I'd do (prepare for extensive answer):

## Enable filtering by year

First of all, you want to be able to filter your records by year. I think your approach of enabling filtering via URL is fine, so that's what we're going to do:

#### 1. Get paginated list, optionally filtered by year

In your controller, add/modify the following method:

```
public function PaginatedReleases($year = null)
{
    $list = NewsReleaseArticlePage::get()->sort('ArticleDate', 'DESC');
    if ($year) {
        $list = $list->where(array('YEAR("ArticleDate") = ?' => $year));
    }
    return PaginatedList::create($list, $this->getRequest());
}
```

This will allow you to get all entries, or only the ones from a certain year by passing in the `$year` parameter.

#### 2. Add a year action to your controller

```
public static $allowed_actions = array(
    'year' => true
);

public function year()
{
    $year = $this->request->param('ID');
    $data = array(
        'Year' => $year,
        'PaginatedReleases' => $this->PaginatedReleases($year)
    );
    return $data;
}
```

After running `dev/build`, you should already be able to filter your entries by year by changing the URL (eg. `mypage/year/2016` or `mypage/year/2015` etc.)

## Use a form with a dropdown to filter

Add the following to your controller to create a form to filter your entries:

```
public function YearFilterForm()
{
    // get an array of all distinct years
    $list = SQLSelect::create()
        ->addFrom('NewsReleaseArticlePage')
        ->selectField('YEAR("ArticleDate")', 'Year')
        ->setOrderBy('Year', 'DESC')
        ->addGroupBy('"Year"')->execute()->column('Year');

    // create an associative array with years as keys & values
    $values = array_combine($list, $list);

    // our fields just contain the dropdown, which uses the year values
    $fields = FieldList::create(array(
        DropdownField::create(
            'Year',
            'Year',
            $values,
            $this->getRequest()->param('ID')
        )->setHasEmptyDefault(true)->setEmptyString('(all)')
    ));

    $actions = FieldList::create(array(
        FormAction::create('doFilter', 'Submit')
    ));

    return Form::create($this, 'YearFilterForm', $fields, $actions);
}
```

Implement the `doFilter` function. It simply redirects to the proper URL, depending what year was selected:

```
public function doFilter($data, $form)
{
    if(empty($data['Year'])){
        return $this->redirect($this->Link());
    } else {
        return $this->redirect($this->Link('year/' . $data['Year']));
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the Form name to the `allowed_actions`:

```
public static $allowed_actions = array(
    'YearFilterForm' => true, // <- this should be added!
    'year' => true
);
```

Now delete your `<select>` input field from your template and replace it with: `$YearFilterForm`.

After running `dev/build`, you should have a page with a form that allows filtering by year (with working pagination)

## Enable AJAX

With AJAX, we want to be able to load only the changed portion of the page. Therefore the first thing to do is:

#### 1. Create a separate template for the content that should be loaded asynchronously

Create a template `Includes/ArticleList.ss`

```
<div id="ArticleList" class="RecentNews">
    <% loop $PaginatedReleases %>
       $ArticleDate.format("F j, Y"), <a href="$URLSegment">$H1</a><br />
    <% end_loop %>

    <% if $PaginatedReleases.MoreThanOnePage %>
        <% if $PaginatedReleases.NotFirstPage %>
            <a class="prev pagination" href="$PaginatedReleases.PrevLink">Prev</a>
        <% end_if %>
        <% loop $PaginatedReleases.Pages %>
            <% if $CurrentBool %>
                $PageNum
            <% else %>
                <% if $Link %>
                    <a href="$Link" class="pagination">$PageNum</a>
                <% else %>
                    ...
                <% end_if %>
            <% end_if %>
        <% end_loop %>
        <% if $PaginatedReleases.NotLastPage %>
            <a class="next pagination" href="$PaginatedReleases.NextLink">Next</a>
        <% end_if %>
    <% end_if %>
</div>
```

Your page template can then be stripped down to:

```
$YearFilterForm
<% include ArticleList %>
```

After `dev/build`, everything should work as it did before.

#### 2. Serve partial content, when page is requested via AJAX

Since this affects calls to `year` and `index` (unfiltered entries), create a helper method in your controller like this:

```
protected function handleYearRequest(SS_HTTPRequest $request)
{
    $year = $request->param('ID');
    $data = array(
        'Year' => $year,
        'PaginatedReleases' => $this->PaginatedReleases($year)
    );

    if($request->isAjax()) {
        // in case of an ajax request, render only the partial template
        return $this->renderWith('ArticleList', $data);
    } else {
        // returning an array will cause the page to render normally
        return $data;
    }
}
```

You can then add/modify the `index` and `year` methods to look identical:

```
public function year()
{
    return $this->handleYearRequest($this->request);
}

public function index()
{
    return $this->handleYearRequest($this->request);
}
```

#### 3. Wire everything with some JavaScript

```
(function($) {
    $(function(){
        // hide form actions, as we want to trigger form submittal
        // automatically when dropdown changes
        $("#Form_YearFilterForm .Actions").hide();

        // bind a change event on the dropdown to automatically submit
        $("#Form_YearFilterForm").on("change", "select", function (e) {
            $("#Form_YearFilterForm").submit();
        });

        // handle form submit events
        $("#Form_YearFilterForm").on("submit", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            $("#ArticleList").addClass("loading");
            // submit form via ajax
            $.post(
                form.attr("action"),
                form.serialize(),
                function(data, status, xhr){
                    $("#ArticleList").replaceWith($(data));
                }
            );
            return false;
        });

        // handle pagination clicks
        $("body").on("click", "a.pagination", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#ArticleList").addClass("loading");
            $.get(
                $(this).attr("href"),
                function(data, status, xhr){
                    $("#ArticleList").replaceWith($(data));
                }
            );

            return false;
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

## Conclusion

You now have a solution that gracefully degrades on non JS devices. Filtering via dropdown and pagination is AJAX enabled. The markup isn't defined in JS *and* in templates, it's just the SilverStripe templates that are responsible for the markup.

All that is left to do is add a nice loading animation when content refreshes ;)

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I really appreciate the time you took making it so thorough. After trying it out, it seems to do exactly what I need, and I definitely learned some great stuff.