# How to catch AJAX requests (SilverStripe 3.4)

Tags: silverstripe

I have a form that's applied on every page throughout the site and need it to be sent asynchronously without taking the user anywhere.

I can't figure out out to catch the sent data... I'm using Page.php for it because I assume since it's on every page it belongs there; I ran through the ajax tutorial on the SilverStripe website but that doesn't really cover the topic, only the example site that's being worked on. I read it, I watched the video and still can't figure it out.

What I need to know is what URL to send data to (*I assume its any since Page applies to all pages, right?*) and how to catch the request...
At the moment I have the script ready to send info but don't understand what I need to do server-side.

Here's what I have in the back-end atm, what can I do to make this work?

**Page.php**

```
 class Page_Controller extends ContentController {

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'flagDated'
    );

    public function flagDated(SS_HTTPRequest $request){

        echo $request;

        if($request->isAjax()){
            //
        }
    }

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        Requirements::javascript('themes/three-two/js/flag-dated.js');
    }
 }
```

---

**Update**

I think I've somewhat got it working. I found that rearranging what I had gets me closer to where I need to be. The issue right now is that the `$request->isAjax()` is failing and it's returning `basic return`...
I'm still unsure of what I'm doing wrong -- **I found that adding** `?ajax=1` **at the end of the request fixes this**

```
 class Page extends SiteTree {

    // ...

    public static $allowed_actions = array(
        'flagDated'
    );

 }

 class Page_Controller extends ContentController {

    public function flagDated(SS_HttpRequest $request){

        if($request->isAjax()){
            return '$request';
        }

        return 'basic return';
    }

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        Requirements::javascript('themes/three-two/js/flag-dated.js');
    }
 }
```

FireFox console returns `200` `Response: basic return`

---

**Update II**

<del>Alrighty, so I've got the data receiving server-side but having a slight problem getting the data into `postVars`.</del>

So as I was writing my update I began getting `403` `Forbidden` `Action 'flagDated' isn't allowed on this handler.` returns... I didn't change anything to do with permissions AFAIK, what would be causing this? Is it the `$allowed_actions`? Because it was working the whole time since my last update... `PHP Fatal error:  Access level to VirtualPage_Controller::$allowed_actions must be public (as in class Page_Controller)`
**Hmm... I found that if I change the** `$allowed_action` **in** `VirtualPage.php` **from** `private` **to** `public` **it works again and I get a** `200` **response... what's the issue here? Why is that page affecting another?**

Comment: I wrote this gist a while ago to help: https://gist.github.com/dhensby/5057163

Comment: Not sure, but maybe the answer I provided for this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37685842/) helps? It uses AJAX based form submission.
Basically you just write a regular form and submit handler and then submit the form via JS/AJAX instead of a normal form submit. In the backend there isn't much that changes…

Comment: That looks very much like what I need! I've added the code I currently have, that's as far as I got to, what would I need to do next?

Answer (score 5):

You submit the data to the form "action" (the property on the form element). This is the form handler.

I wrote a gist quite some time ago to handle ajax form submissions (https://gist.github.com/dhensby/5057163).

Here's a complete example of how to set up a basic Form that accepts submissions by both AJAX and traditional default browser behaviour (as is good practice):

#### Adding the form to our controller

First we need to define our form; your `Page_Controller` should look something like this:

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {

    /**
     * A list of "actions" (functions) that are allowed to be called from a URL
     *
     * @var array
     * @config
     */
    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'Form',
        'complete',
    );

    /**
     * A method to return a Form object to display in a template and to accept form submissions
     *
     * @return Form
     */
    public function Form() {
        // include our javascript in the page to enable our AJAX behaviour
        Requirements::javascript('framework/thirdparty/jquery/jquery.js');
        Requirements::javascript('mysite/javascript/ajaxforms.js');
        //create the fields we want
        $fields = FieldList::create(
            TextField::create('Name'),
            EmailField::create('Email'),
            TextareaField::create('Message')
        );
        //create the button(s) we want
        $buttons = FieldList::create(
            FormAction::create('doForm', 'Send')
        );
        //add a validator to make sure the fields are submitted with values
        $validator = RequiredFields::create(array(
            'Name',
            'Email',
            'Message',
        ));
        //construct the Form
        $form = Form::create(
            $this,
            __FUNCTION__,
            $fields,
            $buttons,
            $validator
        );

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * The form handler, this runs after a form submission has been successfully validated
     *
     * @param $data array RAW form submission data - don't use
     * @param $form Form The form object, populated with data
     * @param $request SS_HTTPRequest The current request object
     */
    public function doForm($data, $form, $request) {
        // discard the default $data because it is raw submitted data
        $data = $form->getData();

        // Do something with the data (eg: email it, save it to the DB, etc

        // send the user back to the "complete" action
        return $this->redirect($this->Link('complete'));
    }

    /**
     * The "complete" action to send users to upon successful submission of the Form.
     *
     * @param $request SS_HTTPRequest The current request object
     * @return string The rendered response
     */
    public function complete($request) {
        //if the request is an ajax request, then only render the include
        if ($request->isAjax()) {
            return $this->renderWith('Form_complete');
        }
        //otherwise, render the full HTML response
        return $this->renderWith(array(
            'Page_complete',
            'Page',
        ));
    }

}
```

Adding these functions to `Page_Controller` will make them available on **all** page types - this may not be desired and you should consider if it would be more appropriate to create a new page type (such as ContactPage) to have this form on

Here we've defined methods to:

- Create the `Form`
- A form handler (to save or send the submissions somewhere, this runs after the `Form` has successfully validated it's data)
- A `complete` action, which the user will be sent to after successfully completing the form submission.

#### Customising out templates for easy content replacement

Next we need to set up our templates - modify your Layout/Page.ss file:

```
<% include SideBar %>
<div class="content-container unit size3of4 lastUnit">
    <article>
        <h1>$Title</h1>
        <div class="content">$Content</div>
    </article>
    <div class="form-holder">
        $Form
    </div>
        $CommentsForm
</div>
```

This is taken from the default simple theme, with a minor addition that the form is now wrapped in a `<div class="form-holder">` so that we can easily replace the form with a success message.

We also need to create a `Layout/Page_complete.ss` template - this will be the same as above except the `form-holder` `div` will be:

```
<div class="form-holder">
    <% include Form_complete %>
</div>
```

Next create the `Includes/Form_complete` include - it's important to use an include so that we can render **just** this section of the page for our responses to AJAX requests:

```
<h2>Thanks, we've received your form submission!</h2>
<p>We'll be in touch as soon as we can.</p>
```

#### Creating the javascript form listener

Finally, we need to write our javascript to send the form by AJAX instead of the default browser behaviour (place this in mysite/javascript/ajaxform.js):

```
(function($) {
    $(window).on('submit', '.js-ajax-form', function(e) {
        var $form = $(this);
        var formData = $form.serialize();
        var formAction = $form.prop('action');
        var formMethod = $form.prop('method');
        var encType = $form.prop('enctype');

        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function(jqXHR,settings) {
                if ($form.prop('isSending')) {
                    return false;
                }
                $form.prop('isSending',true);
            },
            complete: function(jqXHR,textStatus) {
                $form.prop('isSending',false);
            },
            contentType: encType,
            data: formData,
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                window.location = window.location;
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var $holder = $form.parent();
                $holder.fadeOut('normal',function() {
                    $holder.html(data).fadeIn();
                });
            },
            type: formMethod,
            url: formAction
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This javascript will submit the form using AJAX and on completion it will fade the form out and replace it with the response and fade it back in.

#### For advanced users:

With this example all forms on your site will be "ajaxified", this may be acceptable, but sometimes you need some control over this (for example, search forms wouldn't work well like this). Instead, you can modify the code slightly to only look for forms with a certain class.

Amend the `Form` method on `Page_Controller` like so:

```
public function Form() {
    ...
    $form->addExtraClass('js-ajax-form');
    return $form;
}
```

Amend the javascript like so:

```
$(window).on('submit', '.js-ajax-form', function(e) {
    ...
})(jQuery);
```

Only forms with the class `js-ajax-form` will now act in this way.

Comment: Just to clear things up, it's not the ajax side of it that I'm having trouble with it's how to receive the data in the framework. _Side note: thanks for that link anyway, does it have docs or is that 1 comment all that's needed to use it?_

Comment: No other docs. Can you link to the video and docs you've been following, please?

Comment: Sure - [Linky](https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/ajax-behaviour-and-viewabledata). That's the main one and then pretty much any search result you find on various search engines (I've been looking for ~7 hours so far, really don't get what is needed for this to work)

Comment: That video doesn't address forms. With Forms you set up the usual form method and form handler (or action) on the controller. see [the form docs](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/tutorials/forms/#processing-the-form). Forms generally work with AJAX requests pretty well. If you need a special response, your form handler can have a `if Director::is_ajax()` check to return a different response for ajax submissions

Comment: You're right, it doesn't, but that's the only official mention of using ajax with that framework that I found. It would've been great if they gave some sort of overview for overall usage with relevant examples then devs could adapt it to what they need to do... That's my idea of documenting functionality anyway

Comment: I think we can both agree on that!

Comment: Here's a complete example: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/silverstripe/4126/forms/16420/creating-a-simple-ajax-form#t=201607292014562740533

Answer (score -2):

I've managed to get it working.
Here is my solution for anyone else looking how to ajax with SilverStripe regardless of what the use case is.

---

**HTML**
Pretty basic, just presents the user with some fields to enter things in.

```
 <div class="flag-dated-container hidden">

     <div class="modal-window">

         <div class="header">
             <h1>Flagging $Title</h1>
             <div class="close" data-action="close" title="Close">X</div>
         </div><!-- . header -->

         <form>
             <input type="text" placeholder="This content is..." />
             <textarea placeholder="Explain the issue in full detail..."></textarea>
         </form>

         <div class="buttons">
             <div data-action="close">Cancel</div>
             <div data-action="send">Send</div>
         </div><!-- . buttons -->

     </div><!-- . modal-window -->

 </div><!-- . flag-dated -->
```

**JavaScript / ajax**
Just 2 things to note, use the name of the function you're using at the end of the `url` you're sending data too. Mine is the same page so I use the current URL and append `flagDated` into it with `?ajax=1` so `isAjax()` passes when the request gets sent

```
 var container = document.getElementsByClassName('flag-dated-container')[0];

 // Interaction functionality
 container.addEventListener('click', function(e){

     var target = e.target,
         userInput = container.querySelectorAll('input, textarea');

     if(target.dataset.action === 'send'){

         /*
             My function in the controller is called 'flagDated'
             so that's what I append to the end of the URL
             and the ?ajax=1 is to ensure it passes the isAjax() check
             in the controller
         */
         var r = new XMLHttpRequest(),
             url = window.location + 'flagDated?ajax=1',
             data = '';

         // Create the param to send
         data = 'title=' + encodeURIComponent(userInput[0].value);
         data += '&body=' + encodeURIComponent(userInput[1].value);

         r.onreadystatechange = function(){

             if(r.readyState === 4 && r.status === 200){
                 // Success, do something
             }
             else if(r.readyState !== 4 && (r.status === 400 || r.status === 500)){
                 // failed
             }
         }
         r.open('POST', url); // We use the current URL because it doesn't matter what the target is
         r.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
         r.send(data);
     }
 });
```

**PHP**
This is the part I had most trouble with. The `$allowed_actions` needs to be in the `Controller` and set to `private`. The `title` and `body` I set in my JS script is access using those same vars in `$request->postVars('myVar');`

```
 class Page_Controller extends ContentController {

     private static $allowed_actions = array(
         'flagDated'
     );

     public function flagDated(SS_HttpRequest $request){

         if($request->isAjax() && $request->isPost()){

             $title = $request->postVar('title');
             $body = $request->postVar('body');

             $email = new Email(
                 'from@email.com',
                 'to@email.com',
                 'Flagged as Dated: ' . $title,
                 $body
             );

             $email->send();
         }
         else
             // Not ajax or post, do something else.
     }

     public function init() {
         parent::init();
         Requirements::javascript('themes/three-two/js/flag-dated.js');
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please don't take this personally, but this should not be designated as the right answer. This example circumvents almost every security feature of SilverStripe, from xsrf protection to html injection protection. It's also just a bad and inaccessible implementation of ajax forms. this is just a stripped down example, those that don't know won't realise and will probably use this as an example of how to do ajax and send emails with SS. This may solve your particular problem but it won't help others and will spread bad practice.

Comment: This was the only way I found, if you know of a better way feel free to add it in or correct the answer. Also it's not just form data I needed Ajax for, this was just the example of what I wanted and the only way I found to collect and process requests

Comment: I've provided a detailed example on the SO docs site and linked to it for you. If this is how you've implemented your form you're leaving your site open to significant security vulnerabilities.