# SilverStripe 3.6.2 - Sorting Paginated Data Objects by Dropdown selection triggers 404 error

Tags: php, jquery, pagination, silverstripe

A couple years ago, I setup a paginated list of News Article Pages that were sorted by year based on a dropdown field selection: [SilverStripe - Create pagination based on dropdown selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37685842/silverstripe-create-pagination-based-on-dropdown-selection)

I'm now trying to do the same thing but this time, the News Articles are data objects. Otherwise, everything else is the same.

The problem is I cannot get it to work this time and I'm not sure why. I'm following the same steps but when I select a year from the dropdown, I am taken to a 404 page on my site, and, in the Network tab in Chrome, there is a 404 status for the url:
[image]

I can see that the year value is not getting passed to the page's code for processing, but I'm not sure why as it did work -- and still works -- on the other SilverStripe site I was working on from the old post I linked to.

Here is the code that I have right now:

```
;(function($) {
   $(function(){
        // hide form actions, as we want to trigger form submittal
        var newsYearFilterForm = $("#Form_YearFilterForm");
        // automatically when dropdown changes
        newsYearFilterForm.find(".Actions").hide();

        // bind a change event on the dropdown to automatically submit
        newsYearFilterForm.on("change", 'select[name="Year"]', function(e){
            newsYearFilterForm.submit();
        });

        // handle pagination clicks
        $("body").on("click", "a.pagination", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
           // $("#ArticleList").addClass("loading");
            $.get(
                $(this).attr("href"),
                function(data, status, xhr){
                    $("#ArticleList").replaceWith($(data));
                }
            );

            return false;
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

NewsLandingPage.php

```
<?php

class NewsLandingPage extends Page
{

    private static $description = 'News Landing page.';

    private static $db = array();

    private static $has_one = array();

}

class NewsLandingPage_Controller extends Page_Controller
{

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'renderNewsItem',
        'YearFilterForm',
        'year',
    );

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }

    private static $url_handlers = array(
        '$NewsItem!' => 'renderNewsItem',
    );

    public function getAllNews()
    {
        $newsList = NewsItem::get()->sort('NewsDate', 'DESC');
        return new PaginatedList($newsList, $this->getRequest());
    }

    public function renderNewsItem(SS_HTTPRequest $request)
    {
        $newsItemName = $request->param('NewsItem');
        if ($newsItemName != "") {
            $newsItem = NewsItem::get()->filterAny(array(
                'NewsItemSlug' => $newsItemName
            ))->first();

            if ($newsItem) {
                $arrayData = array(
                    'NewsItem' => $newsItem,
                );

                return $this->renderWith(array('NewsArticle', 'Page'), new ArrayData($arrayData));
            } else {
                return $this->httpError(404);
            }
        }

    }

    public function handleYearRequest(SS_HTTPRequest $request)
    {
        $year = $request->param('ID');
        $data = array(
            'Year' => $year,
            'PaginatedReleases' => $this->PaginatedReleases($year)
        );

        if ($request->isAjax()) {
            // in case of an ajax request, render only the partial template
            return $this->renderWith('ArticleList', $data);
        } else {
            // returning an array will cause the page to render normally
            return $data;
        }
    }

    //creates a form to filter through news releases by year
    public function YearFilterForm()
    {
        // get an array of all distinct years
        $list = SQLSelect::create()
            ->addFrom('NewsItem')
            ->selectField('YEAR("NewsDate")', 'Year')
            ->setOrderBy('Year', 'DESC')
            ->execute()->column('Year');

        // create an associative array with years as keys & values
        $values = array_combine($list, $list);

        // our fields just contain the dropdown, which uses the year values
        $fields = FieldList::create(array(
            DropdownField::create(
                'Year',
                '',
                $values,
                $this->getRequest()->param('ID')
            )->setHasEmptyDefault(true)
                ->setEmptyString('Show all')
                ->setAttribute('data-urlpattern', $this->Link('year') . '/YYYY')
        ));

        $actions = new FieldList(
            FormAction::create('doFilter', 'Submit')
        );

        return Form::create($this, 'YearFilterForm', $fields, $actions);
    }

    public function year()
    {
        return $this->handleYearRequest($this->request);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->handleYearRequest($this->request);
    }

    //redirects to the proper url depending on which year is selected for sorting news
    public function doFilter($data, $form)
    {
        if (empty($data['Year'])) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Link());
        } else {
            return $this->redirect($this->Link('year/' . $data['Year']));
        }
    }

    //created a paginated list of news released by year
    public function PaginatedReleases($year = null)
    {
        $list = NewsItem::get()->sort('NewsDate', 'DESC');
        if ($year) {
            $list = $list->where(array('YEAR("NewsDate") = ?' => $year));
        }

        return PaginatedList::create($list, $this->getRequest())->setLimitItems(10);
    }

}
```

NewsItem.php

```
class NewsItem extends DataObject{
    private static $db = array(
        'NewsName'              => 'Varchar(255)',
        'NewsItemSlug'              => 'Varchar(250)',
        'NewsDate'              => 'SS_Datetime',
        'NewsLocation'          => 'Varchar(255)',
        'NewsArticle'           => 'HTMLText',
        'NewsArticleSummary'    => 'HTMLText',
        'SortOrder'             => 'Int',

    );

    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'NewsName',
        'NewsDate',
        'NewsItemSlug',
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'NewsImage'             => 'Image',
        'NewsUrlForHomePage'    => 'SiteTree',
        'Page'                  => 'Page'
    );


    public function onBeforeWrite() {
        parent::onBeforeWrite();
        if ($this->NewsItemSlug == ""){
            $linkName = $this::getLinkName();

            if ($linkName == ""){
                $linkName = str_replace(array(" ",":","%","$","#","@","!","^","&","*","(",")","'",";","<",">","/","?","[","]","{","}","\\","|","`","~","=","+","’",",","."),"-",strtolower(str_replace("&","and",str_replace(".","",$this->NewsName))));
            }


            $this->NewsItemSlug = $linkName;
        } else {
            $this->NewsItemSlug = str_replace(array(" ",":","%","$","#","@","!","^","&","*","(",")","'",";","<",">","/","?","[","]","{","}","\\","|","`","~","=","+","’",",","."),"-",strtolower(str_replace("&","and",str_replace(".","",$this->NewsItemSlug))));
        }
    }
    public function getLinkName() {
        if ($this->NewsItemSlug != "" && !is_null($this->NewsItemSlug)){
            return $this->NewsItemSlug;
        }
        return str_replace(" ","-",strtolower(str_replace("&","and",$this->NewsName)));
    }
    public function LinkingMode() {
        return Controller::curr()->getRequest()->param('ID') == $this::getLinkName() ? 'current' : 'link';
    }
    public function Link() {
        $newsLandingPage = NewsLandingPage::get()->first();

        $linkName = $this::getLinkName();

        if ($linkName){
            return $newsLandingPage->Link($linkName);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function canView($member = null){
        return true;
    }

    public function canEdit($member = null) {
        return true;
    }

    public function canCreate($member = null) {
        return true;
    }

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->removeFieldFromTab("Root.Main","PageID");
        return $fields;
    }
}

class NewsItemAdmin extends ModelAdmin {
    private static $managed_models = array(
        'NewsItem',
    );
    private static $url_segment = 'NewsItems';
    private static $menu_title = 'News';
}
```

NewsLandingPage.ss

```
<% include BreadCrumbs %>
<div class="container container-intro-copy" style="background-color:#fff;opacity:1.0;">
    <h1 class="intro-copy h1">$H1</h1>
    <div class="intro-copy">$Content</div>
    $YearFilterForm
    <% include NewsList %>
</div>
```

NewsList.ss

```
<div id="ArticleList" class="container careers-list">
    <div class="row">
        <% loop  $PaginatedReleases %>
            <div class="career-item col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12 item bio-detail aos-init aos-animate" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200" style="margin-top:30px;">
                <div class="box-for-resources top-box-style">
                    <div class="box-resources-left"><img src="$NewsImage.URL" class="image-resources-cmmm"></div>
                    <div class="box-resources-right">

                        <h3 class="name left" style="color:#002f65 !important; float: left; clear: both;">$NewsName</h3>
                        <p class="box-resource-copy text-date"><em>$NewsDate.FormatI18N('%B %d, %Y') ($NewsLocation)</em></p><br />
                        <div class="careers-copy">$NewsArticleSummary</div><br />
                        <a href="$Link">Read Article</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% end_loop %>
    </div>
</div>
```

The news page successfully loads all the articles by default and the links to each article work properly. The dropdown form has the correct list of years based on the range the articles have.

Comment: Did you do a `dev/build`? Maybe your `allowed_actions` weren't picked up? Your `allowed_actions` contains _way_ to many items too… it should only contain `'YearFilterForm'` and `'year'`

Comment: Look at the `allowed_actions` from the answer I've given you the last time. It doesn't need any more that that.

Comment: I removed the extra items from the $allowed_actions and I have done a dev/build?flush=all and dev/build?flush=1. Still no change :\

Comment: Maybe you should simplify the code and just have the allowed_actions, url_handlers and the action renderNewsItem with a simple echo to confirm thats. Or use xdebug to step through the process and see what fires the 404. First you need to figure and coform the actions work right, then check are you passing data to the actions right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a conflict with your `url_handlers` and the actions you're calling on the controller.

```
'$NewsItem!' => 'renderNewsItem',
```

The above line matches all actions to `renderNewsItem`. Eg. `yoursite.test/controller/YearFilterForm` will also be matched by this…

You should add some static part to your handler that displays a news item. So your `url_handlers` would be:

```
'show/$NewsItem!' => 'renderNewsItem',
```

Then you'd have to adjust your `NewsItem->Link` method accordingly.
I also suggest you use the `URLSegmentFilter` to create your slugs… eg.

```
public function onBeforeWrite() {
    parent::onBeforeWrite();
    // only rebuild the slug when news-name has changed
    if ($this->isChanged('NewsName', DataObject::CHANGE_VALUE)) {
        $filter = URLSegmentFilter::create();
        $t = $filter->filter($this->NewsName);

        // Fallback to generic name if path is empty (= no valid, convertable characters)
        if (!$t || $t == '-' || $t == '-1') {
            $t = "news-{$this->ID}";
        }

        $this->NewsItemSlug = $t;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what I finally figured out last night. Well, that the $url_handlers aspect of the code was tripping me up. I haven't had a chance to try your code but I will.